# signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)-android 10 (API 29) mostly

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, android-10.0, lottie

I am getting signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)
android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const

on android vitals crashes more than 3500K user impacted within a month, most of the crashes are happening on android 10 devices.

Not using any NDK library directly

Tried searching in all places but couldn't find any solution or hint so far

```
backtrace: 
#00 pc 000000000023834c /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1032) 
#00 pc 0000000000373578 /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawBackwardsProjectedNodes(SkCanvas*, android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaDisplayList const&, int)+496) 
#00 pc 000000000037353c /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawBackwardsProjectedNodes(SkCanvas*, android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaDisplayList const&, int)+436) 
#00 pc 00000000003d7a00 /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkCanvas::onDrawDrawable(SkDrawable*, SkMatrix const*)+1020) 
#00 pc 0000000000238500 /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1468) 
#00 pc 00000000003d7790 /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkCanvas::onDrawDrawable(SkDrawable*, SkMatrix const*)+396) 
#00 pc 0000000000238500 /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+1468) 
#00 pc 000000000036e204 /system/lib64/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+308) 
#00 pc 000000000027c5c0 /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaPipeline::renderFrameImpl(android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue const&, SkRect const&, std::__1::vectorandroid::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode, std::__1::allocatorandroid::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>> const&, bool, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const&)+468) 
#00 pc 0000000000279390 /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaPipeline::renderFrame(android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue const&, SkRect const&, std::__1::vectorandroid::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode, std::__1::allocatorandroid::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>> const&, bool, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, sk_sp, SkMatrix const&)+152) 
#00 pc 0000000000278fcc /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaOpenGLPipeline::draw(android::uirenderer::renderthread::Frame const&, SkRect const&, SkRect const&, android::uirenderer::LightGeometry const&, android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue*, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, bool, android::uirenderer::LightInfo const&, std::__1::vectorandroid::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode, std::__1::allocatorandroid::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>> const&, android::uirenderer::FrameInfoVisualizer*)+388) 
#00 pc 00000000002d7250 /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::draw()+660) 
#00 pc 00000000002d6368 /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13DrawFrameTask11postAndWaitEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvvEEclEv$c303f2d2360db58ed70a2d0ac7ed911b+380) 
#00 pc 00000000002e5dc0 /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+228) 
#00 pc 00000000002e5aa8 /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+584) 
#00 pc 0000000000013744 /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+328) 
#00 pc 00000000000d4358 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36) 
#00 pc 0000000000071aa8 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

Comment: A little googleing shows that libhwui is known to somehow segfault. Do you know how to reproduce it? Could you please update your question with the libs (e.g. React Native?) you are using in the app and what code-paths are triggering this callstack?

Comment: Unable to reproduce it, and not using react native